# tch-rs, how to convert tch.Tensor into a rust vec?

Tags: rust, tensor, torch-rust

I have a tch::Tensor , and I want to convert it to a rust vec, how can I do it?

I tried the following solution , but it does't work

```
use tch::Tensor;
fn main(){

   let t: Tensor = Tensor::from_slice(&[1.1 ,2.2 ,3.3 ]); 

   let v  = Vec::<f32>::from(t);

}
```

Can someone give me the solution codes?

Tried as above.

And I search the tch-rs document ,failed to found the  api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to use [`TryFrom`](https://docs.rs/tch/latest/tch/struct.Tensor.html#impl-TryFrom%3CTensor%3E-for-Vec%3CT%3E) since the `Tensor` loses the static type information:

```
let v = Vec::<f32>::try_from(t).expect("wrong type of tensor");
```

NOTE: I'm not sure if this as-written will succeed or fail since you are creating it from a slice of `f64` but trying to get it as a `Vec` of `f32`. I'm unfamiliar with the library so I don't know if it will do a conversion and I can't test it myself.

Comment: If this won't work, you can convert to `Vec<f64>` and use [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck) to extract a `&[f32]` out of it.

Comment: Thanks. I use the Tensor::copy_data method to solve it.